# How to acess the airflow cli when deployed with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

When I deploy Apache Airflow with docker-compose, and run it via docker-compose run -d, the CLI Container stops automatically, and I have no Chance to exec into it. I am using the standard docker-compose file, I only deletet the profiles: debug option where the cli is defined.

I first run: docker-compose run
Then: docker exec -it airflow-airflow-cli-1 bash

It then says: Container is Not Running.

Why has it stopped and how can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you following the steps in the [official guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html)?

Using the following steps from the guide:

1. Do `curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.0/docker-compose.yaml'`
2. In that folder `docker compose up airflow-init`
3. `docker-compose up`
4. `docker exec -it <FOLDER_NAME>-airflow-scheduler-1 /bin/bash`

I end up in the scheduler container where you can use the Airflow CLI. (I ran `airflow tasks test example_bash_operator runme_0 '2023-01-01'` to test)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to modify the docker-compose such that I would always end up in the schedulers terminal when executing docker-compose run? Without having to run the docker exec command?

Comment: The way I've seen this solved is by putting both docker-compose and the exec command in a bash script and calling that script. I am not aware of a way of setting a command to run in the shell _outside_ of the container in the docker config. But I am not that familiar with docker configuration, so there might be a way.